# Disable Google Maps zoom amount

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to allow zooming on Google Maps but only allow the *amount* of zoom?

I found  this code to disable zooming but is there a way I can allow users to zoom in so much?

```
options = $.extend({
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}, options);
```

For example I dont want zoome to go any higher than `zoom: 15,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the maxZoom property in [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).